# kill liferay previous session if the same user logged in again

Tags: session, liferay-6

I want to kill liferay's session of an user. For example, it allows more than one login for the same user(is there any way to control this?). If the user logged in, i got a session id and i am putting into a context. And the same user logging from some other system / browser / place, I am getting new session id for the login. Now, I have old and new session id in my context.  (similar solution available [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10698605), but I haven't tried yet, which can be done for newly logged in session)

Is it possible destroy the old session by / with session id.? by doing this, if the user clicks any link on the page (old session's page), will it redirect to logout page / configured (session expired) page if any.?

(Using Liferay 6.1 CE)

Comment: don't let your user re-login if they already have an active session? Hook the authentication process to sniff and disallow the new session

Comment: i can not restrict that, because if any network failure / browser crash happened, user will try from some other system / device. So, it will be a problem. For now, I am thinking to reduce ``session-timeout``. Anyway its not the solution.

Comment: Well, you **will** need to address this via the authentication hook - you will need to do a check during any authorization filter for session registered for the user. Your choice on what do to with that information @ that point. Killing the prior session and starting a new one i suppose is fine - look @ the auth hook as mentioned: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/service-security-layers

Comment: @brandt, seems its completely authentication part. I am looking for session management part.